# Calves muscles pain when running

Tags: running

Recently when I run I always get my calves muscles rigid like stones. If I run 10 minutes, I don't stop because I go out of breath, rather because I feel pain. I tried to rest some days, but it doesn't help. I also tried to take magnesium and potassium.
Nothing to do: my muscles are rigid. Maybe also because of the cold. I also have stretching, it helps a bit but I still have the problem. What can I do?

Comment: Is this a medical advice request? Am I sick? Ridicolous.

Comment: "**General health** and medical advice is off-topic here." Sure, you may not be sick, but without professional direction, how would we know if it is not an underlying condition? Nonetheless, your question has been answered and welcome to Sports SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with this has to do with getting the blood flowing, and my calve muscles hurt alot as I begin running, until I warm up.

What I try is before I head out, not to sit, rather to move around, and bounce up on my toes as I move around (Activate calf muscles).

Then I run for 6 minutes, and walk for 8 before continuing my run.  This usually gets my calf muscles warmed up and blood flowing, so they do not go anaerobic and get lactic acid buildup.

Sadly, this does not work every time, and I sometimes find I need a longer warm up.  Your mileage may vary.